# Сохранение последовательности чисел в массив

Tags: java, массивы

Есть код решения системы Лоренца, мне нужно сохранять все решения x,y,z на каждой итерации в соответствующие решениям массивы, как это лучше сделать? Как перевести потом массивы в строку?

```
public class Butterfly {

public static double dx(double x, double y, double z) {
    return -10*(x - y);
}

public static double dy(double x, double y, double z) {
    return -x*z + 28*x - y;
}

public static double dz(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x*y - 8*z/3;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = 0.0, y = 20.0, z = 25.0; //Начальные позиции x, y и z 
    double dt = 0.001;

    // Используем метод эйлера первого порядка
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {


        // собственно решение
        double xnew = x + dx(x, y, z) * dt;
        double ynew = y + dy(x, y, z) * dt;
        double znew = z + dz(x, y, z) * dt;
        x = xnew; //переопределяем значения x, y, z для следующей ите
        y = ynew;
        z = znew;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, то подойдёт двумерный массив. [50000][3].

Comment: double[][] xArray = new double[50000][3];
    xArray = x; // в коде это будет так?

Comment: мне нужно 5000 решений x, y и z поместить в массив. А потом полученный перевести в строку, если это возможно. @Dmig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам требуется записать в память 3 числа 50000 раз. Для этого отлично подходит двумерный массив. По сути, это массив массивов, таким образом Вы будете хранить 50000 массивов из 3 чисел. Имплементация:

```
//Определяете массив перед циклом
double[][] xArray = new double[50000][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {

    double xnew = x + dx(x, y, z) * dt;
    double ynew = y + dy(x, y, z) * dt;
    double znew = z + dz(x, y, z) * dt;
    x = xnew;
    y = ynew;
    z = znew;
    xArray[i][0] = x;
    xArray[i][1] = y;
    xArray[i][2] = z;
    /**
      Запись в ячейку двумерного массива, где i - итерация, а
      значения x, y, z будем хранить в 0, 1 и 2 индексе малого массива
    **/
}
```

Подробнее о двумерных массивах можно почитать на [сайте А. Климова](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/array.php).